# How to encrypt with AES android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I wanna encrypt the string with secret key and Iv. But i am not getting correct encryption. can any one tell me how to do this.
My string is abc but when decrypt the string it is contain special charaters in this.
i followed this link:
https://www.cuelogic.com/blog/using-cipher-to-implement-cryptography-in-android/

```
package com.reshhhjuuitos.mhhhkoiyrestos.footer;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
public class MCrypt {
    private String iv = "1234567890123456";            // Dummy iv (CHANGE IT!)
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private String SecretKey = "1&BZ6pqSu1w2%7!8w0oQHJ7FF79%+MO2";
    public MCrypt() {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            //cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
// Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE = Constant for encryption operation mode.
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
    private static String padString(String source) {
        char paddingChar = 0;
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;
        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
            source += paddingChar;
        }
        return source;
    }
    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        } else {

            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(
                        str.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);

            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array) {
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : array) {
            int intVal = b & 0xff;
            if (intVal < 0x10)
                hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal));
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }
    public byte[] decrypt(String text) throws Exception {
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
// Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE = Constant for decryption operation mode.
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(text));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

MainACTVITIY.JAVA

```
MCrypt mycrypt = new MCrypt();
        String dummyStr = "abc";
        try {
            String encryptedStr = mycrypt.byteArrayToHexString(mycrypt.encrypt(dummyStr));
            String decryptedStr = new String(mycrypt.decrypt(encryptedStr));
            Log.v("Tag_en",""+encryptedStr);
            Log.v("Tag_de",""+decryptedStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output:Tag_en:5b49ac218b93ee5315c25a0e40b3e9de42e6ecadf0827062b22d4421da99dc5a
 Tag_de: abc��������������������������

Comment: You're padding your plaintext twice, once manually yourself and again with PKCS5Padding. Just use the PKCS5Padding that's done by the Cipher object.

Comment: Completely disregarding James' comment (which is very correct BTW) to repost the title like a parrot, I wonder what you planned to achieve with that...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I thought it might be your hex encode/decode, but they work. So I wrote some quick encryption and tested it against your class.

The problem is your padding. I don't understand why you are padding your string to length 16, but it is the null characters you have appended to your string that are unprintable. So either don't pad the string, or strip the padding nulls during decryption to rebuild the exact string you encrypted.

For clarity, maintainability and re-usability, you should really do just one clear logical operation in each of your methods, i.e. padding should be done before you pass the string to the encryption method, so the encryption method just encrypts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use functions like these:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

And invoke them like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); // bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  

byte[] keyStart = "this is a key".getBytes();
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
sr.setSeed(keyStart);
kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();    

// encrypt
byte[] encryptedData = encrypt(key,b);
// decrypt
byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(key,encryptedData);
```

This should work, I use similar code in a project right now.